# How to run shell tools from kotlin scrip

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-script

I am trying to rewrite several sh-scripts into kotlin scripts. How can I run shell commands or execute binaries accessible in the PATH variable from a kotlin script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shell script is using the JVM (java virtual machine) to execute. Which means you can access the inner workings of this by using `Runtime.getRuntime()`.

The most notable af the return is the `exec`-method

This class has been present since java version 1.0, but here is the javadocs for java 11: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html